# How to update data from api while fetching new data?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

In react-native I am able to update data in my screen from api while fetching with react-stack-navigator , but when i am using react-drawer-navigator I can't . I have tried many times with using 'willFocus' listener . It didn't work . How can i do this process?

```
            catId:null,
            subCatByCatId:[],
            loading:false,
            catTitle:'',
             cat_list:[]
        }

  async componentDidMount(): void {
this.setState({loading:true});
const {navigation}=this.props;
this.WillFocus=navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    async(payload)=>{
this.setState({
    catId:this.props.navigation.state.params.catId
},async ()=>{
    const {catId}=this.state;
    const uri = "https://bilettm.com/api/v1/category/"+catId+"/events"
const apiCall = await fetch(uri)
    const categories = await apiCall.json();
    this.setState({
        subCatByCatId:categories.sub_cats,
        loading:false,
    })

})

    }

);



  }

  componentWillUnmount(): void {
        this.WillFocus.remove();

  }
```

Comment: Can you add some details, code?